# How to enable my nfs server?

Tags: server, mount, process, nfs

My service status shows

```
service nfs status
Unit nfs.service could not be found.
```

I checked unix deamons

```
ps aux | grep nfsd
mikigm     12022  0.0  0.0  20452  2636 pts/0    S+   11:03   0:00 grep --color=auto nfsd
ps aux | grep mountd
mikigm     12168  0.0  0.0  20452  2476 pts/0    S+   11:05   0:00 grep --color=auto mountd
```

And

```
showmount -e
clnt_create: RPC: Program not registered
```

Then

```
systemctl list-unit-files nfs*
UNIT FILE          STATE   VENDOR PRESET
nfs-common.service masked  enabled      
nfs-config.service static  -            
nfs-idmapd.service static  -            
nfs-utils.service  static  -            
nfs-client.target  enabled enabled
```

What does masked state mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of `masked` as a version of `disabled` with the added feature of blocking the service from being started; even manually. Anything linked to this service will be routed to `/dev/null`, which is the Linux way of shouting into a void.

Some services can be unmasked like this:

```
sudo systemctl unmask {service}
```

If a mask cannot be removed, there may be an override file in place blocking the (re-)activation of the service.

Comment: This is an example of removing an override https://blog.ruanbekker.com/blog/2017/12/09/unmask-a-masked-service-in-systemd/